# How can I concatenate values in an Excel pivot, as opposed to summing or counting

Tags: excel, concatenation, pivot-table

Say I have the following data:

```
Col1   Col2
------------
Bob    Green
Bob    Green
Bob    Green
Chris  Blue
Chris  Blue
Chris  Red
Dave   Blue
Dave   Green
Dave   Red
```

A default Pivot Table in Excel would yield:

```
Col1   Col2
------------
Bob    Green
Chris  Blue
       Red
Dave   Blue
       Green
       Red
```

Is there any way to concatenate on Col2 (specifically, with separators), so I end up with this?:

```
Col1   Col2
------------
Bob    Green
Chris  Blue,Red
Dave   Blue,Green,Red
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is not possible from a PivotTable. However, if `Bob` is in A2 a formula in C2 like:

```
=IF(A1=A2,C1&", "&B2,B2)
```

and another in D2 of:

```
=A2=A3
```

both copied down to suit, may serve if you "fill in the gaps" (either in the PT or with Go To Special, Blanks, `=`, Up, Ctrl+Enter) then select all, Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top and filter to delete rows showing `TRUE`.

[TEXTJOIN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) is now available on some versions.